# Dropdown menu with fadein and height

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to create a nav menu like the one here(http://themes.fuelthemes.net/bouncy/) for practice, and I have come pretty close but mine doesn't quite look (the animation isn't as smooth) as good as the one in the example. The source code is very large and I cannot find how the author creates the animations in the css code or through javascript. Here is what I have so far. Could someone please take a look and tell me what I am doing wrong?

The method I am using to make the menu slide down is by using the max-height property and I am making it fade in with the opacity property.

Bulk of animation code:

```
.menu > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    transition: max-height 0.2s, opacity 0.4s;
    max-height: 500px;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
.dropdown {
    max-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    background: #2c2c2c;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

My JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cn2fZ/

Comment: I would just increase transition(s) time: http://jsfiddle.net/cn2fZ/1/

Comment: The one I am trying to copy is just as long, but it slows down at the very end I think. Maybe a different easing function...

Answer (score 0):

They aren't using Transistions what the code is is something like this

http://jsbin.com/onituc/1/

or

this http://jsbin.com/onituc/2/edit

Both are different styles

The first one uses the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` functions combined with the `delay` function. As well as using the fadeIn, we can change the `fadeIn` to other stuff like
`show`
`slideDown`

The second one just uses the `slideUp` and `slideDown` functions combined as well with the `mouseenter` `mouseleave`

Hope one of these two help you, if you need more help please comment